# Error: unknown flag: --scope while adding secret in a Databricks-backed scope

Tags: scope, databricks

I am refering to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secrets to add a secret to Databricks-backed scope using below command
`databricks  secrets put --scope <scope-name> --key <key-name>`
However I am getting error Error: unknown flag: --scope
I tried removing --scope paramenter but then it gave error Error: unknown flag: --key

Answer (score 0):

I tried databricks CLI help and got below
Usage:

databricks secrets put-secret SCOPE KEY [flags]

This finally resolved my issue

```
databricks secrets put-secret <myDatabricksScopeName> <KeyName>
```

Comment: The documentation still uses syntax for old Databricks CLI, while you have installed the new one